# How to cancel and restock order using Shopify API?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I'm building a simple order validation microservice for my Shopify store. Basically, the microservice will validate new orders and automatically cancel them is there is some kind of validation error (compliance reasons). I'm looking at the Shopify orders API, but it's still not completely clear to me the proper way to use it.

https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/orders/order#cancel-2020-01

This microservice would be triggered by the "Order created" web hook, so there is no concern that the order is partially or completely fulfilled.

What I want to do is to cancel the order, refund the payment to the customer, add a note, and restock the items. How can I do this with the Shopify API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you need to cancel the order, for that you can use:

```
POST /admin/api/2020-01/orders/#{order_id}/cancel.json
```

After that you must calculate the refund:

```
POST /admin/api/2020-01/orders/#{order_id}/refunds/calculate.json
```

And then refund it using:

```
POST /admin/api/2020-01/orders/#{order_id}/refunds.json
```

Look in to **restock_type** for returning the items to the total count.

An at any point you can make a request to:

```
PUT /admin/api/2020-01/orders/#{order_id}.json
```

in order to add the note.

Please have in mind that you need to take in consideration the **currency** and **location_id** if the store is using multi-locations.

And that should be the whole process.

Comment: Ok thanks you. However the one other thing that I'm confused about is do I need to use the refunds API if I'm cancelling an "unfulfilled" order? or does Shopify return the money back to the customer automatically?

Comment: @cgossain depends of the your set payment method but if you are using the standard Shopify payments the customer will be charged when he finish the checkout process. So it doesn't matter if the order is not fulfilled, he will be still charged for the products. While I can still be mistaken here but this is the standard behaviour.